# Best Practice? Passing object References back from segues

Tags: ios, reference, segue

Good morning.

I have been working through a lot of tutorials the past year, and have seen several methods of passing reference back up the View Hierarchy with Storyboards. I was wondering what some best practices are, and more importantly any pitfalls using the following methods:

1. Protocol - the child view implements a protocol, that the parent view sets itself as the delegate to and responds to messages. This can be used to pass back information to the delegate. The Child does not need to know anything about the reason it was called, it does it's job, and sends back whatever information it was asked for.
2. Public property of the Child ViewController that has the model reference. On the segue you retrieve the reference to the destination view Controller. This view controller has the model property exposed publically. You pass in your reference to the model. I personally like this method - can't see any real pitpalls with it. then when the child makes changes the model is changed directly. at the point `[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES]` gets called to or however you navigate off/dismiss the view controller you have the information in the model you want.
3. ANYTHING ELSE?  - someone else has a good idea, i'd love to hear it.

Thanks for anyone's input on this. I know there are always more than 1 way to skin a cat, I just want to skin the cat cleanly and quickly.  (-Sorry cat)

Steve

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, in addition to the two options you enumerate, there are a couple of other options:

1. Use unwind segue (iOS 6 and later), and you can pass data to the "destination" (the controller you're unwinding to) via `prepareForSegue`;
2. Use singleton for your master model object;
3. Use Core Data (or SQLite) for persistent storage; or
4. Use notifications or key value observation (though this is much better for communicating data updates to multiple objects).

Personally, I'll generally use a protocol when it's just a matter of a presented view controller wanting to inform the presenting view controller of some information, but each of these techniques have their respective uses.

Comment: The Core Data option is interesting -  I am implementing a solution right now, and unless I am mistaken , if you pass an entity object (the Core Data Wrapper object that is created using created NSmanaged object Subclass) to the target child controller the child could simply update the object and those changes are just updated in the DB - correct?

Comment: @SESPROUL I'll defer questions on the Core Data specifics to guys who do more Core Data than I, but conceptually that's right. For cross-platform compatibility, I tend to do more SQLite stuff, so I don't feel terribly qualified to discuss Core Data specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need there is another option and no segue is required.

The child view controller could create its own object or obtain a known shared reference of any object. Creating its own object would be good for adding a new item to a table. Obtaining a known shared reference would be good for something like a settings object.

When the child view controller is ready to be dismissed it posts a notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postName:MyAppDidCreateNewItem object:self.item];
```

or

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postName:MyAppDidUpdateSettings object:self.settings];
```

The parent view controller registers as an observer to the notification. When the notification happens, the parent view controller can use `notification.object` to get the reference and update itself.

Comment: this uses standard notifications? the child posts the parent is a subscriber right?

Comment: Yes, simple standard local notifications: the child posts messages and the parent is the observer.

Comment: I have been learning so much different iOS the last 6 months, that this is all just now starting to come into focus. Thanks for all the help everyone. I wrote up all my cope to use protocols, not I am going to add in the reverse segue.  This Notifications is what I expect to review next!